# Python Equivalent of Scheme/Lisp CAR and CDR Functions

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

I am currently trying to implement `fold`/`reduce` in Python, since I don't like the version from `functools`. This naturally involved implementing something like the Lisp `CDR` function, since Python doesn't seem to have anything like it. Here is what I am thinking of trying:

```
def tail(lat):
  # all elements of list except first
  acc = []
  for i in range(1,len(lat)):
    acc = acc + [lat[i]]
```

Would this be an efficient way of implementing this function? Am I missing some kind of built-in function? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you like the version from `functools`? Do you want it to be curried, so `reduce(f)` returns a function that takes an iterable and reduces `f` over it? Or is because it's one function with an optional parameter rather than two separate functions that you can pass alternately to some other higher-order function? Or did a supervillain named "Reduce-O" kill your father so you can only use the function if it's named `fold`? (Some of these are more reasonable than others, but that's not the point; knowing what you want to change may make it easier to suggest how to do it.)

Comment: I mainly don't want to use `functools.reduce` because it requires the use of a lambda (or am I wrong about that?) and python lambdas aren't very flexible. I want a version that can use any binary function, no matter how complex it is. I'm currently trying to implement Gaussian elimination, which is basically all list operations, so I thought some kind of fold would make it a lot easier.

Comment: There’s no such thing as “a lambda” in Python. lambda isn’t a different kind of function, it’s just a different way of defining the one and only kind of function there is. And reduce, like almost everything else in Python, doesn’t even require a function; it’ll take bound methods, partials, instances of your own classes with a custom call method, etc. So you’re going through a lot of trouble for nothing.

Comment: Thank you! I will keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 6):

"Something like the Lisp CDR function" is trivial:

```
acc[1:]
```

This will be significantly faster than your attempt, but only by a constant factor.

---

However, it doesn't make much sense to do this in the first place. The whole point of CDR is that, when your lists are linked lists stored in CONS cells, going from one cell to its tail is a single machine-language operation. But with arrays (which is what Python lists are), `acc[1:]`—or the more complicated thing you tried to write, or in fact any possible implementation—allocates a whole new array of size N-1 and copies over N-1 values.

The efficiency cost of doing that over and over again (in an algorithm that was expecting it to be nearly free) is going to be so huge that the constant-factor speedup of using `acc[1:]` is unlikely to be nearly enough of an improvemnt to make it acceptable.

Most algorithms that are fast with CDR are going to be slow with this kind of slicing, and most algorithms that are fast with this kind of slicing would be slow with CDR. That's why we have multiple data structures in the first place: because they're good for different things.

---

If you want to know the most efficient way to fold/reduce on an array—it's the way `functools.reduce` (and the variations of it that libraries like `toolz` offer) do it: just iterate.

And just iterating has another huge advantage. Python doesn't just have lists, it has an abstraction called iterables, which include iterators and other types that can generate their contents lazily. If you're folding forward, you can take advantage of that laziness. (Folding backward does of course take linear space, either explicitly or on the stack—but it's still better than quadratic copying.) Ignoring that fact defeats the purpose.